# Rails external link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to give external link, however it always prepend with "localhost:3000" unless i am specifying url starting with *http* or *https* . Whenever i make it start with *[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)* it refuse to go to external link but combine it to current page.

```
 <div class="col-10 d-flex justify-content-center gap-2">
                <% @user.links.each do |link| %>
                  <% if link.url.length > 1%>
                   <div>
                    <%= link_to  link.url ,target: "_blank", class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
                        <span><%= link.title %></span>
                    <% end %>
                   </div>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
</div>
```

Where i am doing wrong? I was expecting the get clean url from link. But when i am in `localhost:3000/users` page it gives me `localhost:3000/users/www.youtube.com`

Comment: I am unable to recreate this issue in isolation: [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/linkto#)

Comment: You need to start the link with `https://`, otherwise the link will be assumed to be a relative link within the current domain.

Comment: You've answered your own question by stating that you need to start the url with https:// as all external urls should be and as @sevenseacat has already stated. That is the cleanest url you can get

Comment: How do you store your links?

Comment: There are 2 types of links: absolute and relative. Probably you tried to use relative. Use absolute instead

Comment: What does `@user.links` contain? Are they absolute urls (starting with `https://<domain>/...`) or relative paths (starting with `/...`)?

Comment: I had to edit the links prepend them with "http" or "https" then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You absolutely need **https://** to specify that it is external link
2. you can create a **helper** method to use from your template to create correct external links with something like this:

```
    def external_link(link)
      return link if link.include?('https://')
    
      link.prepend('https://')
    end
```

Then in your code just use:

```
    link_to external_link(link), target: '_blank', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```